# Best way to remove paste in pad footprint in Altium

Tags: altium, pad, paste

I have a top only pad in a footprint. I don't need any open window on the the top solder layer so I set the tented option enable for my pad...

[image: Tented option]

But even if the top solder is off (no window for this pad, it is tented), I have top paste for this pad... see picture :

[image: top paste on no window]

So, I have to switch to manual paste mask expansion and put -999 mils into value to be sure it disappear...

[image: negative paste value]

For me it's a mistake/bug from Altium. Because it have no sense to have paste on a pad without any window on top solder mask on it to received. So does not a tented pad should automatically disable the associated paste for this external layer ?

Related information : 
https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Idea/9120

Comment: I've been looking into this as well and there does not seem to be a better option than the negative expansion at the moment. In my case I have a tented net-tie that still gets solder paste on top of the soldermask. Clearly Atlium knows not to put past on through hole pads, why not an option for surface mount?